# How to assign template ref to nested object property

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

My script tag looks like this:

```html
<template>
<div>
  <div ref="publicKey.element">Public</div>
  <div ref="privateKey.element">Private</div>
</div>
</template>
<script setup>
const publicKey = {
  element: ref(null),
  onClick: () => alert('public clicked'),
}
const privateKey = {
  element: ref(null),
  onClick: () => alert('private clicked'),
}
</script>
```

Basically, instead of assigning a template ref to a top-level composition api ref, I want to apply it to a ref that's nested in an object.

The problem is that the above ref="publicKey.element" doesn't do anything - when I check the value under the "element" property, there's just the regular ref object and the _value is null.

How do I put an actual element there?

Answer (score 3):

[Use the function syntax of the ref="" attribute](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for)
The docs show an example with v-for, but you can also use it without v-for

```html
<div>
  <div :ref="el => publicKey.element.value = el">Public</div>
  <div :ref="el => privateKey.element.value = el">Private</div>
</div>
```